# setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener in android java

Tags: android, insets

I have a toolbar which is overlapping with the system bars so I am setting the insets with the toolbar. I have the implementation below which is not doing anything and it is still at the same place. I am trying to set the margins on left, right and top.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(getWindow(), false);

        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(myToolbar, (v, windowInsets) -> {
            Insets insets = windowInsets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars());
            // Apply the insets as a margin to the view. Here the system is setting
            // only the bottom, left, and right dimensions, but apply whichever insets are
            // appropriate to your layout. You can also update the view padding
            // if that's more appropriate.
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams mlp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
            mlp.leftMargin = insets.left;
            mlp.topMargin = insets.top;
            mlp.rightMargin = insets.right;
            v.setLayoutParams(mlp);

            return WindowInsetsCompat.CONSUMED;
        });
```

Comment: toolbar and its parent should have `fitSystemWindows` set. Also keep in mind only coordinatorlayout dispatches insets to all children (that fit system windows), default viewgroup behavior is to send it only to one.

Comment: I did use `fitSystemWindows` in toolbar but it is not working and overlaps as before.